# sqlite: query to add (subtract) cells from adjacent rows and put result in new column

Tags: sqlite, cursor, calculated-columns

I am examining a .sqlite file in FireFox's SQLite Manager and need to see if any data was not collected.  An example is worth a thousand words:

```
ReadDate            ReadValue
1361900350183.00    137
1361899753183.00    139
1361900053183.00    138
```

The are no primary keys and the table is NOT sorted by ReadDate or time. [Changing the input table is not an option!]
What I'd like to do is produce with simple SQL a table that looks like this:

```
ReadDate            ReadValue  TimeOffset 
1361899753183.00    139
1361900053183.00    138        300000  // this is ReadDate(1) - ReadDate(0)  
1361900350183.00    137        297000  // this is ReadDate(2) - ReadDate(1)
```

This would allow me to inspect the data and see if any data values were not captured (TimeOffset would be much greater than 300000).  I could also write an additional query to get a COUNT of all TimeOffsets beyond a threshold.
I'm having trouble getting going on what I imagine is a simple exercise.  I know how to do joins and sorts (order by), but here I need to compare one row to another.  Do I need a cursor?  And how to get the extra column?  I have a gut feeling that if I just knew the vocabulary a little better, I'd be able to come up with the search terms and find the answer quickly.
Many thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, [add an (empty) column](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) to your table:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN TimeOffset NUMERIC;
```

Then, the `TimeOffset` for each record is the difference between the `ReadDate` column of *this* record and of the record with the next smaller `ReadDate`, i.e, the record with the largest `ReadDate` that is still smaller than this one's:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET TimeOffset = ReadDate - (SELECT MAX(ReadDate)
                             FROM MyTable AS t2
                             WHERE t2.ReadDate < MyTable.ReadDate);
```

Comment: Thanks CL!  That worked great.  And in SQLite Manager too!  I was exported the table to Excel and manipulating it that way but this is way easier.